# Solve value for X in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, equation

I want to take an equation from users to pass into my data to get the values. I was trying to use eval and using logic to find exp, log, and replace it with math function. However, eval is not supporting curly brackets or box brackets.

My equation will have only one independent variable (i.e y = f(x)). My current approach is following:

```
import math
x = 5
eqn = '(x**2)+(x*2)+exp(5)+exp(2)+log(2)'

if 'exp' in eqn:
    eqn = eqn.replace('exp' , 'math.exp')

if 'log' in eqn:
    eqn = eqn.replace('log' , 'math.log')


print(eval(eqn))
```

How do I support other brackets? Is there any better approach than this? Thanks.

Comment: Add ``eqn.replace('[', '(')`` and so on (other kind of parentheses) after ``eqn = '(x**2) . . .`` before the if. Do the same for ``^``. I don't think that user will write power as ``**`` instead of ``^``.

Comment: Note that both of your `if`s are unnecessary - `.replace()` will work just fine (returning the input string unchanged) if there's nothing to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python reserves [] and {} braces for other uses rather than just order of operations. You can just use nested parenthesis for the same effect.

More traditional mathematical notation would write nested parenthesis like this: `[(2+2)*4]**2`

In python, you could just write `((2+2)*4)**2`

You could convert them like you've done with the other equation elements:

```py
eqn = eqn.replace('[', '(')
eqn = eqn.replace('{', '(')
eqn = eqn.replace(']', ')')
eqn = eqn.replace('}', ')')
```

Comment: Users may need to add the other brackets as equations, in general, have them. What should be my approach in this case?

Comment: You could just convert them like you did your log and exp. I've edited my answer with code to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that myself and found you posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

SymPy's solve() function can be used to solve equations and expressions that contain symbolic math variables.

Equations with one solution:
The code section below demonstrates SymPy's solve() function when an equation is defined with symbolic math variables.

```
 from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

y = symbols('y')
eq1 = Eq(y + 3 + 8)


    sol = solve(eq1)
    sol
```

Output:

```
[-11]
```

Equations with two solutions:

If you specify the keyword argument dict=True to SymPy's solve() function, the output is still a list, but inside the list is a dictionary that shows which variable was solved for.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

y = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq(x*2 -5x + 6)


sol = solve(eq1, dict=True)
sol
```

Output:

```
[{x: 2}, {x: 3}]
```